# Removing fields from the JSON response

Tags: php, json, wordpress, wp-api

I am using the WP REST API (WP API) and am retrieving the posts with this call below.

```
wp-json/posts
```

There are 170 posts and the JSON file is 3.1MB which takes about 9 seconds to download. When pulling the posts the only data I need is the title and featurd image, therefore 99% of the JSON file is not needed.

I have been looking at this method below that removes fields from the response, it works to an extent but still doesn't remove fields such as `ID` and `author`.

```
function remove_extra_data( $data, $post, $context ) {
  unset( $data['ID'] );
  unset( $data['status'] );
  unset( $data['excerpt'] );
  unset( $data['type'] );
  unset( $data['author'] );
  unset( $data['content'] );
  unset( $data['parent'] );
  unset( $data['date'] );
  unset( $data['modified'] );
  unset( $data['format'] );
  unset( $data['slug'] );
  unset( $data['guid'] );
  unset( $data['menu_order'] );
  unset( $data['comment_status'] );
  unset( $data['ping_status'] );
  unset( $data['sticky'] );
  unset( $data['date_tz'] );
  unset( $data['date_gmt'] );
  unset( $data['modified_tz'] );
  unset( $data['modified_gmt'] );
  unset( $data['meta'] );
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'json_prepare_post', 'remove_extra_data', 10, 3 );
```

So what is the best method to remove all unwanted fields included fields that have nested content?

Comment: provide your own interface that doesn't generate a bunch of data you'd just end up throwing away anyways?

Comment: Do you have the access to the json builder? If so, you could just modify to send only required fields.

Comment: As others have suggested, you are approaching this problem from the wrong direction.  You should provide your own method of generating exactly what you need.

Comment: I admit that the wp-json extension offers a poor API. It is not possible to say exactly which fields you want from a post. However, have you tried this url: `wp-json/posts?context=parent`. Following the documentation, it should deliver less data per post.

Comment: @hek2mgl thankyou for your response. Yes I am struggling to find a bullet proof method for this as it would be great if the users of WP-API could configure what fields are added in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is being decoded strictly as an array, and not an object, you could use something like `array_filter()` to filter out those properties which you don't want.

```
// This will only work in PHP 5.6+
$keys = [
    'ID',
    'author',
];
return array_filter($data, function($k) use ($keys) {
    return in_array($k, $keys, true);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```